# Oracle: Check constraint for both alphabetical and numerical characters in varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, character, check-constraints

So I want to check that the varchar2 is in the format of 4 alphabetical characters then 3 numerical characters e.g. AABB123 or LMNO987

So far I've tried:

```
CONSTRAINT Code_Check check (REGEXP_LIKE(Code,'[^A-Z][^A-Z][^A-Z][^A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))

CONSTRAINT Check_Code check (Code LIKE '[^A-Z][^A-Z][^A-Z][^A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

CONSTRAINT Check_Code check (Code LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]')

CONSTRAINT Check_Code check (Code regexp_LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]')

CONSTRAINT Check_Code check (Code LIKE '[^A-Z]{4}[0-9]{3}')
```

But simply get the error:

```
insert into Table1 (Code) values ('HELP555')
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (BOB.TABLE1_CHECK_CODE) violated
02290. 00000 - "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause: The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check
*Action: do not insert values that violate the constraint.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expressions are not right, and the way you've used is pretty cumbersome.

Instead, you can opt to use [POSIX character classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm#1006817). In your specific case, it will be like so:

```
[[:alpha:]]{4}[[:digit:]]{3}
```

so the constraint check is

```
CONSTRAINT Code_Check check (REGEXP_LIKE(Paper_Code,'[[:alpha:]]{4}[[:digit:]]{3}')
```

This checks that there are 4 alphabetic characters, followed by 3 numeric.

Example on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6e16/5) & more info available at [regexp cheatsheet](http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--Regexp-Cheat-Sheet_856.htm)